# Obtain feature importance from a mixed effects random forest

Tags: python, random-forest

I am an `R` user running for the first time `python3.7 64bit` on Windows.
I was trying to get permutation importance from a mixed effects random forest using `PermutationImportance` from package `eli5`.
Dataset for reproducibility can be found [here](https://github.com/manifoldai/merf/blob/master/notebooks/MERF%20Example.ipynb).

Fit:

```
merf = MERF(n_estimators= 500, max_iterations= 100)
np.random.seed(100)
merf.fit(X_train_merf, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train)
```

Feature importance:

```
perimp = PermutationImportance(merf, cv = None, refit = False, n_iter = 50).fit(X_train, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train)
```

The above code produces this error

```
TypeError: fit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

But `fit()` contains only 4 arguments...

Is it possible to obtain feature importance at all from `merf` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the merf or eli5 module, but I can tell you why that exception is happening.

If you look into the documentation of the [PermutationImportance Module](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/sklearn.html#eli5.sklearn.permutation_importance.PermutationImportance) and its API you can see the following definition of the **fit()** method:

```py
    fit(X, y, groups=None, **fit_params)
```

Those two stars before the last parameter mean it's an [keyword argument](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). So in fact this method can take 3 positional arguments and many keyword arguments. But that also means you need to name your fourth parameter(s). Inside the method you get a dictionary for this parameter and the method needs to know how to handle it.

Example:

```py
def my_fit(X, **fit_params):
    print(fit_params)

my_fit("positional argument", x=1,y=2,z=3)               
>>> {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

I don't use eli5 so I can't tell you what keywords to use or if it is possible to obtain feature importance from merf objects at all, but the error is fixed by just giving your last parameter a name like:

```py
perimp = PermutationImportance(merf, cv = None, refit = False, n_iter = 50).fit(X_train, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train=y_train)
```

Hopefully the method knows what to do with a parameter named like this.

Comment: This is the error I get after running the PermutationImportance function now:

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\...\permutation_importance.py", line 194, in fit
   self.estimator_ = clone(self.estimator)
   File "C:\...\sklearn\base.py", line 60, in clone
   % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
  TypeError: Cannot clone object '<merf.merf.MERF object at 
  0x0000024CEB863F28>' (type <class 'merf.merf.MERF'>): it does not seem to be 
  a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods`

Comment: It means, (as you already assumed) that the merf object you are giving to the fit method is not compatible with scikit-learn because it does not have a get_params method. The **fit()** method awaits a scikit-learn estimator. Sadly I don't know enough about the math background of what you are trying here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and from the source code I figured out that you can pull the feature importance from the randomforest model object, which is part of MERF.

```
mrf.fit(X_train, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train)
feat_importance=mrf.trained_fe_model.feature_importances_
```